# How to deal with comments that are no longer actual / relevant

Tags: discussion, comments

The question is in the title, here some examples:

- The comments asks for more information which gets added to the question with an edit. The comment is no longer needed.
- The comment is from 2006 and no longer correct since to updates (Browsers, Framework etc.)

I think those comments should be deleted, because they have no more relevance and ar just noise. And if a good and relevant comment would pop up where there are already 10 no more relecvant ones, nobody will see it but the owner of the post who is getting an alert.

Comment: _"How to deal with comments having no more actual"_... yes? No more actual... what?

Comment: So flag as obsolete.  What's the problem?

Comment: @Cerbrus Thx, edited; was not what I intend to do, but your comment now is one of those ^^

Comment: I'd argue that the comment is still (a little) funny. That said, If they _really_ have to be gone, you can just flag them as "obsolete". For my first comment on here, though, I wouldn't be surprised if the flag got declined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The comments asks for more information which gets added to the question with an edit. The comment is no longer needed.

Flag the comment as "Obsolete".

> The comment is from 2006 and no longer correct since to updates (Browsers, Framework etc.)

Well, Stack Overflow dates from 2008, so this won't happen :-)

But seriously - you *could* flag these comments as obsolete, but that would be wrong. The "Obsolete" flag refers to obsolence of the discussion, *not* to the obsolence of the subject matter. The fact that there is new technology does not mean that the old technology has gone away. **Some people are required to maintain legacy systems, and the comment may still be relevant to them.**
Also, this would require the moderators to judge the comment on technical merits, which is not what flags are for.

In such a case, I'd leave a comment pointing out that the earlier comment is outdated.
You point out, rightfully, that new comments might be lost among existing upvoted comments. In this case, consider if the other comments still have value. If not, you can flag these. Sometimes, it may be easier to just flag the post, and point out that an entire comment thread is outdated.

Anyway, before you flag - consider if it is really noise. Moderators are busy enough as it is. But if you conclude that a comment or comment chain really is noise - flag it.

Comment: The third paragraph of your answer cannot be emphasized enough. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to deal with the long tail of programming questions. The fact that a technology has become "obsolete" in some people's eyes does not mean that no one is interested in it anymore. There are, I kid you not, developers out there who still have to make their sites compatible with IE 6. A massive purge of all the IE 6-related information from Stack Overflow would be a *huge* hindrance to their work, and have a negative impact on their quality of life.

Comment: Please don't abuse flags in an attempt to remove information about topics that are no longer trendy. **The "obsolete" flag reason does not refer to technical obsolescence.** Rather, it refers to practical obsolescence, such as the comment pointed out an improvement that should be made to the answer, and that improvement has already been made. Or the comment refers to an old revision of the answer, and as such, no longer makes sense.

Comment: @CodyGray Noted, thanks for chiming in. I've added some emphasis.